# How to move a div into the space of another after removing it?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, slack

It seems the old Slack desktop UI finally broke, too bad.

So I opened `/slackdevtools` and moved the control strip to the left and then removed the pesky, completely unnecessary tab rail, but an empty space remains:

```
strip = document.querySelector('div.p-control_strip');
document.querySelector('div.p-workspace_switcher_prototype').appendChild(strip);
strip.style.left='0px'
document.querySelector('div.p-tab_rail').remove()
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Desirable: #general is right next to the + sign where "Later" used to be. In other words, how do I force `div.p-client_workspace__layout` to occupy the space which `div.p-tab_rail` used to? That's not even a Slack desktop question , that's a JS/CSS question. Obviously I need to save something before removing it but what? (I know nothing. I am a backend dev.)

Comment: Open the Slack desktop client and type /slackdevtools. That's the HTML...

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector('.p-client_workspace_wrapper').style.gridTemplateColumns = '0 auto';`

If you are here to get the slack ui back approximately where it was, try

```
const domObserver = new MutationObserver(() => {
    let rail = document.querySelector('div.p-tab_rail');
    if (rail) {
        rail.remove();
        let old_strip = document.querySelector('div.p-workspace_switcher_prototype div.p-control_strip')
        if (old_strip) {
            old_strip.remove()
        }
        let strip = document.querySelector('div.p-control_strip');
        document.querySelector('div.p-workspace_switcher_prototype').appendChild(strip);
        strip.style.left=0;
        document.querySelector('.p-client_workspace_wrapper').style.gridTemplateColumns = '0 auto';
    }
});
domObserver.observe(document.body, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true,
});
```